# Difference between sequentially compact spaces and closed sets in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

According to my notes

$K\subset\mathbb{C}$ sequentially compact $\iff$ Every sequence in K has a subsequence which converges to a Point in K

$A\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ closed set $\iff  ((a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ convergent sequence in A $\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n\in A$

I am wondering why the definitions, save for $\mathbb{C}$ are not equivalent

If $A\neq\mathbb{C}$ and $A$ closed set, why does $A$  not have to be necessarily compact? Because the opposite is true. If I take a convergent sequence of a sequentially compact subset $K$ then the convergencepoint has to be by Definition in $K$.

Comment: sequentially compact (in $\mathbb{C}$) is equivalent to "closed and bounded" by Heine-Borel. So unbounded closed sets are counterexamples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,\lvert z\rvert\geqslant1\}$, for instance. It is closed. However, it is not sequentially compact because, for instance, the sequence $1,2,3,\ldots$ has no convergente subsequence. All you can deduce about sequences of elements of $A$ from the fact that $A$ is closed is that **if** one such sequence converges, **then** its limit belongs to $A$.

Comment: You said I should take the sequence $1,2,3,...$ but $2$ and $3$ are not Elements of $A$.

Comment: Why? After all, $\lvert2\rvert=2\geqslant1$ and $\lvert3\rvert=3\geqslant1$.